# Combinations of fields to be unique

Tags: apex, force.com

I have a custom object. I want to put in a business rule so that a combination of two fields must be unique.

So I have Field1 and Field2 and want the combination to be unique:

```
Field1=4, Field2=7
Field1=4, Field2=8
```

is ok

But,

```
Field1=4, Field2=7
Field1=4, Field2=7
```

is not ok

What is the easiest / best way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: How does this question not yet have an accepted answer? Ah OP Hasn't been on since 2013.

Answer (score 27):

The easiest way to do this is to create a `Unique Text field`. Then, concatenate the values of the two fields together and update your `Unique Text Field` with the resulting value using a `Workflow Field Update` or a `before Trigger`.

Smashing the two fields together would essentially create a composite key that can be used to verify uniqueness.

Comment: Innovative use of declarative platform features here :)

Comment: If you go for workflow remember to design criteria that include `ISNEW()`, `ISCHANGED()`, `ISBLANK(unique_field__c)` etc :) Also careful with any datafixes that'd fill the field from Apex - Id fields (lookups) have 18 chars when queried in apex but workflows see only 15 and that's what will be filled in to the unique field.

Comment: We have done this a few times, and at least on one occasion had issues when concatenating two lookup IDs with a workflow rule. We ended up using a trigger to concatenate the fields.

Comment: Another vote for being careful with workflows and ID fields. The custom field either needs to be case sensitive or use the CASESAFEID() function in the formula. See [The mystery of the nondeterministic Salesforce test case](http://www.fishofprey.com/2015/05/the-mystery-of-nondeterministic.html)

Answer (score 3):

The Spring 15 release contains configurable dedupe for standard and custom objects.

You can specify in a more advanced and configurable way exactly what conditions make it a duplicate, which may give you what you're looking for AND be more sustainable as complexity increases.

Duplicate Management section of the release notes: 
http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_sales_duplicate_management_intro.htm#rn_sales_duplicate_management_intro

Comment: It seems like a good idea, but couldn't get it to work for my scenario. I ran into a limitation on the matching rule: "A matching rule can have only one lookup relationship field, but you selected more than one".

Answer (score 3):

I was darned near creating a new trigger, when I realized that it is now 2019, and I am using Salesforce API version 46, which has much easier options for ensuring that a combination of multiple fields are unique.

All you have to do is create a new "Matching Rule" on your desired object (Standard or Custom), activate it, and then create a new "Duplicate Rule" and have it use the "Matching Rule" you just created/activated.

Salesforce have given us a nice YouTube link that does a great of explaining how to go about it::
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy0u5fKBft0

Easy peasy!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a BEFORE trigger. You'll need to run a SOQL query with those values and reject the save if any matching records are found.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this if you're interested in the solution spectrum and look for other better solutions.
It's Before event of record triggered flow to update the unique text field.
https://sfdcsharepoint.medium.com/how-to-prevent-duplicate-child-records-for-the-same-parent-record-8a27371669e1